# Android 6.0-rc on qemu,no mouse

Tags: linux, mouse, android, qemu

I've launched android 6.0 x86 32bit
on qemu.
Works all..but no mouse.
I don't understand why,this is my launch script

```
#!/bin/sh
CDROM=/dev/cdrom
DISCO=android.qcow2
BOOT=c
RAM=3000
ARCH=i386

qemu-system-$ARCH -vga virtio --enable-kvm -drive file=$DISCO,if=virtio,cache=none -m $RAM  -net nic,model=virtio -net tap,ifname=tap3,script=no,downscript=no  -cdrom $CDROM -boot $BOOT -display gtk,gl=on -soundhw ac97,pcspk  -usb -device usb-mouse -cpu host -smp 2
```

Comment: On virtualbox i can avoid this problem cliking on "mouse integration",how on qemu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found using this launch
but is really unstable

```
#!/bin/sh
CDROM=andro.iso
DISCO=android.qcow2
BOOT=c
RAM=3000
ARCH=i386

qemu-system-$ARCH -vga virtio --enable-kvm -drive file=$DISCO,if=virtio,cache=none -m $RAM  -net nic,model=virtio -net tap,ifname=tap3,script=no,downscript=no  -cdrom $CDROM -boot $BOOT -display sdl,gl=on -soundhw hda
```

mouse works fine at least